# How to Pick Column names from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tables which have columns and tables

```
Name
EmpId
Empname
DeptID
DeptName
Employee
Department
```

I have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to get Table names

**Script** :

I have got table names

```
Select T.Name from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I 
INNER JOIN @tbl_columns T 
ON T.name = I.Table_name
```

Here I got table names

Output :

```
Name
Employee
Department
```

I need to get output which table have which column

```
Tbl_Name    ColName 
Employee    EmpId
Employee    Empname
Department  DeptID
Department  DeptName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to connect table name and column name from @tbl_column. If yes I think you can use following script:

```
SELECT   T2.NAME
        ,C.NAME 
FROM SYS.TABLES T1 
INNER JOIN @tbl_columns T2 ON T1.name = T2.NAME
INNER JOIN (SELECT C2.*,C1.object_id 
            FROM SYS.COLUMNS C1 
            INNER JOIN @tbl_columns C2 ON C1.name = C2.NAME
            ) C ON C.object_id = T1.object_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You would include the column name in your `select`:

```
select c.table_name, c.Column_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c join
     @tbl_columns t
     on t.name = c.Table_name
order by c.table_name, c.Column_name;
```

Note that you do not include the `table_schema`, so you can get duplicates.

Comment: the same EmpID and Dept ID have in other tables also but I want result of Employee and Department tables only .I don't want to put those names in where condition